# When I try to SET an attribute from another class to another it doesn't allow me to

Tags: c#, properties, enums

Here's the class:

```
namespace TomeOfNewerth_WPF_
{
    class Hero
    {
        public string faction;
        public string name;
        public HeroType herotype;

        public enum HeroType
        {
            Agility,
            Strength,
            Intelligence
        }
    }
}
```

Now in another class, just for testing I'm tring to instance the Hero class, and set the herotype property, like so:

```
namespace TomeOfNewerth_WPF_
{
    class Spell
    {
        Hero x = new Hero();

        public void lol()
        {
            x.herotype = x.; //How can I set it?
        }
    }
}
```

The only reason I created the herotype property from an Enum was to make the application more robust and not rely on literal strings.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x.herotype = HeroType.Agility;` is normally the code to set it.  You will need to move `HeroType` outside of the class for this to work.

For what it's worth, this might be better off in a constructor, and you should look into exposing class information through Properties instead of public member variables.

Comment: I can't call HeroType enum from my spell class or from any other class for that matter. That's where I'm having trouble.

Comment: Hero.HeroType.Agility - nested class

Comment: Yes, you could use `Hero.HeroType.Agility` but I'd personally recommend not nesting the class and moving the `HeroType` enum out into the namespace if other classes are intended to use it.

Comment: Wow, didn't know you could do that with an Enum. So much to learn, so little time.